# Pyspark - find the index of first positive number in an array column

Tags: python, pyspark

I've got an array column in a pyspark dataframe, and I want to find the index of the first positive number in each array. The data looks like this:

| id | arr |
| --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | -1, -1, -1, -1 |
| Cell 2 | -1, -1, 5, -1 |
| Cell 3 | -1, 3, -1, -1 |

I want to get an output similar to this:

| id | arr | first_positive_element_index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | -1, -1, -1, -1 | null |
| Cell 2 | -1, -1, 5, -1 | 2 |
| Cell 3 | -1, 3, -1, -1 | 1 |

I can do this with a UDF, but the data is quite large making this approach extremely slow. I will prefer if there's a much better way around this without the use of a UDF.

Note: all non-positive numbers are -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `expr` with `array_position`:

```
df_pos = df.select(
    'id', 'arr',
    func.explode('arr').alias('arr_explode_value')
).filter(
    func.col('arr_explode_value')>=0
).withColumn(
    'pos', func.expr('array_position(arr, arr_explode_value)')-1
).groupBy(
    'id'
).agg(
    func.min('pos').alias('pos')
)
df_pos.show(10, False)
+------+---+
|id    |pos|
+------+---+
|Cell 2|2  |
|Cell 3|1  |
+------+---+
```

You can create a dataframe to

1. Explode the array
2. Filter out the positive value
3. Find the smallest index

The rest is to join the reference table back to the dataframe.

```
df.select('id', 'arr').join(df_pos.select('id', 'pos'), on=['id'], how='left')
```

---

Edit 1:

If you don't want to use `explode` because of the long array, you can use the `transform` and `array_position`:

```
df.select(
    'id', 'arr',
    func.transform(func.col('arr'), lambda value: func.when(value>=0, 1).otherwise(0)).alias('transformed_arr')
).withColumn(
    'pos', func.array_position('transformed_arr', 1)-1
).show(
    10, False
)
+------+----------------+---------------+---+
|id    |arr             |transformed_arr|pos|
+------+----------------+---------------+---+
|Cell 1|[-1, -1, -1, -1]|[0, 0, 0, 0]   |-1 |
|Cell 2|[-1, -1, 5, -1] |[0, 0, 1, 0]   |2  |
|Cell 3|[-1, 3, -1, -1] |[0, 1, 0, 0]   |1  |
+------+----------------+---------------+---+
```

Since the `arr` column is array type, you can use `transform` to apply function on the element.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_position` and `filter`. First `filter` to eliminate negative value, then get the first non negative value.

```
filter(arr, x -> x > -1)[0]
```

This will return the first positive value and since you want the index of the value, use `array_position`.

Note that `array_position` is 1-based index, so add -1 to get 0-based.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.withColumn('first_positive_element_index',
                   F.expr('array_position(arr, filter(arr, x -> x > -1)[0]) - 1'))
```

Result

```
+------+----------------+----------------------------+
|    id|             arr|first_positive_element_index|
+------+----------------+----------------------------+
|Cell 1|[-1, -1, -1, -1]|                        null|
|Cell 2| [-1, -1, 5, -1]|                           2|
|Cell 3| [-1, 3, -1, -1]|                           1|
+------+----------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, array_max
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("CreateSampleDF").getOrCreate()
data = [
    ("Cell 1", "-1, -1, -1, -1"),
    ("Cell 2", "-1, -1, 5, -1"),
    ("Cell 3", "-1, 3, -1, -1")
]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["cell", "values"])
df_with_positive_indices = df.withColumn("split_values", expr("split(values, ', ')"))
expr_str = """
    TRANSFORM(split_values, (value, index) -> IF(value > 0, index, NULL))
"""
df_with_positive_indices = df_with_positive_indices.withColumn("pos", expr(expr_str))
# Find the minimum positive index using array_min function
df_with_max_pos = df_with_positive_indices.withColumn("pos", array_min(col("pos")))
df_with_max_pos.show(truncate=False)
spark.stop()
```

use this code to get required output

```html
+------+--------------+----------------+----+
|cell  |values        |split_values    |pos |
+------+--------------+----------------+----+
|Cell 1|-1, -1, -1, -1|[-1, -1, -1, -1]|null|
|Cell 2|-1, -1, 5, -1 |[-1, -1, 5, -1] |2   |
|Cell 3|-1, 3, -1, -1 |[-1, 3, -1, -1] |1   |
+------+--------------+----------------+----+
```

Accept this answer if its fulfill your require output

Comment: if you want any explanation i can add

Comment: I think you need `array_min`. OP is asking for "first" positive number.

Comment: yep,you are right,updated